# What does a warning sign mean in Disk Management?

Tags: windows-server-2003, software-raid, diskmanagement

Here's a (hopefully) easy one: what does the warning sign:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/54795d4ae6.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/54795d4ae6.jpg)

mean in disk management?

The above image is of a mirrored drive (RAID 1) that is in the process of regenerating. Disk 3 was just added as a mirror to Disk 4.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's saying "Don't rip this disk out of the system or you will loose everything". But I'm not 100% sure, so I won't post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically that the disk with the ! is the disk with a invalid copy of the data, if this goes away, data rebuild will be stopped.

Comment: I think it's the other way around, the disk without the ! is the complete disk, becuase Disk 3 is the mirror of Disk 4, and Disk 4 is complete...

Comment: Wait a minute, does the answer and the 1st comment say the same thing? Or am I seeing double?